# Laravel model problems

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to laravel. I created a migration class:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateMusicsTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('musics', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('artist');
        $table->string('album');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('art')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('musics');
}
}
```

a model named Music.php:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Music extends Model {
    protected $table = 'musics';
}
```

a controller named MainController :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Music;


class MainController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $musics = Music::all();

    return view('index', compact('musics'));
}
```

My problem is `Music::all();` in index of controller returns nothing to view but if i remove `App\Music` and use `DB` instead and replace `Music::all()` with `DB::table('musics')->get();` it works fine. Why is that?

Update:
Route.php

```
<?php

get('/', 'MainController@index');
```

Update 2:
index.blade.php:

```
@foreach($musics as $music)
    <span>{{ $music->title }}</span>
@endforeach
```

Comment: How do you verify that it return nothing to view? You should try to use `dd($musics)` to verify if there are any items in the result.

Comment: would you please include your Route.php as well?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek there is no data in view. `dd($musics) returns `Collection {#144 ▼
  #items: []
}`

Comment: @jailbird.phoenix What's your view code? Your `dd()` output shows you've got 144 items in the result. You should be doing something like `@foreach($musics as $music)` on the result.

Comment: @ceejayoz yes, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try `dd($music)` inside your `@foreach` to see what an individual collection item contains.

Comment: Nothing. This whole problem is so wiered

Comment: What does `$musics->toJson()` show?

Comment: can you add `protected $visible = [ 'title','artist','album','name','art'] ` to  your `Music` model and try `dd(Music::all())`

Comment: This might be a typo, however, your route.php should be: `Route::get('/', 'MainController@index');` Also, would you please try removing `
@ceejayoz : `Collection {#144 ▼ #items: [] }` doesn't mean there are 144 items, this collection object is empty. I am still thinking about the problem, this is so weird!

Comment: I don't know what happened but after creating a new laravel project and copying above code, the Music model works. Thanks for your answers to this wiered problem

Comment: "just works" lovely answer, programming is more magic and not at all logical or theoretical.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't believe that "Collection {#144 ▼ #items: [] }" means 144 items are returned. It looks like your array is empty.

Inside php artisan tinker, see what App\Music::all(); returns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside your controller

```
public function index()
{
    $musics = Music::all();

    return view('index', ['musics' => $musics]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the `Model` in your controller after `namespace`. At the top of your controller you should use this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Music.php; //add this line
```